# How can I find the mean of one column of a data frame using a pipe operator in R?

Tags: r, pipe

I'm working on an assignment for one of my classes. We have to se pipe operators to get the mean Height for trees with Volume greater than 13.

So initially, I tried:

```
df <- trees

df %>% filter(Volume > 13) %>% mean(Height)
```

The problem is, then I get a warning message

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(., Height) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I can't figure out how Height is not numeric (it pretty clearly looks like a list of numbers to me), and so I can't complete this question.

Could someone help me out? I've been testing different variations, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the `mean` within `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(Volume > 13) %>%
   summarise(Mean = mean(Height))
```

---

`mean` expects a `vector`, and if we need to do this outside `summarise` `pull` the 'Height' as `vector`

```
df %>%
  filter(Volume > 13) %>%
  pull(Height) %>%
  mean
```

Or use `.$Height`

```
df %>%
    filter(Volume > 13) %>%
    .$Height %>%
    mean
```

---

The warning can be reproduced with `iris` data

```
data(iris)
iris %>%
  mean(.$Sepal.Length)
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
> In mean.default(., .$Sepal.Length) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

It is not related to pipe.  If the input is data.frame, it returns `NA` as the expectation is a `vector`

```
mean(iris['Sepal.Length'])
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
> In mean.default(iris["Sepal.Length"]) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

```
iris %>%
  .$Sepal.Length %>%
  mean
#[1] 5.843333
```